# Anybody know why this canvas isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Need to make a website with a canvas but for some reason nothing shows, it's just white where the canvas should be.. anybody know why? There are also other divs "pushing" the canvas div around, for placement.

On a side note, can i change the size of the canvas when a button is pressed?
For example: the canvas is 100x100px. There is a button on the screen. When pressed, the canvas size changes.

HTML:

```
<section id="Body"> 

    <div id="OtherDiv"></div>

    <canvas id="Canvas">
        Update your browser!
    </canvas>

    <div id="anotherDiv"></div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
#Canvas{
float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;}
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function first(){
    var c=document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
window.addeventlistener("load", first, false);
```

Comment: Possibly because JavaScript is case sensitive so your call should be `window.addEventListener("load", first, false);`.

Comment: You should also be setting the dimensions of the canvas tag to be certain that it is displaying properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First there is no `addeventlistener`. Case matters, it is `addEventListener`.

Second you have no variable `ctx`.

```
function first(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");  // changed c to canvas
    var ctx = canvas .getContext("2d");  // changed canvas to ctx and c to canvas
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
window.addEventListener("load", first, false);  //properly camel cased it
```